# How to get CSS background property to work with toggleClass() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, background, toggle, toggleclass

I added a `toggleClass()` connected to an element that has background property to toggle with different background. Take a look at my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheTravelrr/0k6930pw/5/), so I tested it, and it turns out that the event isn't changing the background no matter whet! I tried everything I know with jQuery. Please, any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance :)

Comment: You should look into CSS specificity. Your class is being successfully applied, but the background on your id is overriding the background on the class. This is a really good representation of why you should avoid using ids in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > ## Use important tag on the class that will override the others

Such as

```
.div1 {
    background:transparent!important;
}
```

Now the gold background disappears when you click toggle

Comment: You helped alot sir :), it's more easy now than choosing classes for all targeted elements, I didn't think that (!important) would solve such a problem. Thank you sir for your time :)

Comment: I would bro, but I must have 15 reputation points at least to vote ;@